# try to access class Class$1 from Class

Tags: java, spring

Recently, when I try to start a spring container, I met a question, the error stack is as follows:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tair_perf' defined in class path resource [tair.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager$1 from class com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:983)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>       at com.taobao.testcase.http.百川.BaiChuanDo.TairRank.(TairRank.java:22)
>       ... 21 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager$1 from class com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
>       ... 34 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager$1 from class com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager
>       at com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager.(MultiClusterTairManager.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
>       ... 36 more

the xml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="tair_perf" class="xxxxx"
          init-method="init">
        <property name="configID">
            <value>xxxx</value>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It seems like there exists a dependency conflict in my project, but I just can't find it.
And this is my own code:

```
public class A {
    public static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("tair.xml");//this where the problem happens.}
```

Comment: It will help if you post class com.taobao.tair.impl.mc.MultiClusterTairManager (or at least the constructor).  Do you have a nested class?  What is the signature of that class?

Comment: OK, but It seems only has the default constructor with no parameter.

Comment: Spring is trying to create bean 'tair_perf'. The error is IllegalAccessError on what looks like a nested class.  If you do not provide information on either, I don't see how we can help.

Comment: Can you post the init method?  The error is coming from there.

Comment: try to post the class of bean:MultiClusterTairManager

Answer (score 0):

The `constructors` and `methods` should be `public` if you want global access.
I'm sure you have problem of visibility to this class `MultiClusterTairManager` because you having this error: `java.lang.IllegalAccessError`